# Firebase SDK not delivering background notification

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a background push notificaiton to my app using Firebase. iOS displays the notification fine but `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is not being called on my `AppDelegate`.

When the device is connected to the debugger, I get the following log messages when the device receives the notification.

> 2016-07-27 15:13:08.234:  FIRMessaging receiving notification in invalid state 2
>
> 2016-07-27 15:13:08.234 MyApp[2513:1130209] Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

It looks to me like Firebase is swizzling `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` but failing to call my implementation because it thinks the app is in an invalid state, which it isn't.

Theres also nothing special with the notification payload that should cause an issue.

```
{
    gcm.message_id: 0:1469652824137045%3aef914a3aef914a, 
    objectId: 7,
    aps: {
        alert: "Your object has been updated"
        content-available: 1
    }
}
```

**Why is Firebase saying the app is in an invalid state and failing to forward notifications to my `AppDelegate`?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misinterpreting the error -- this error is happening because your app's `didReceiveRemoteNotification` handler **is** being called.

The issue is probably that in your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` handler, you need to make sure that you call `completionHandler` with a proper `UIBackgroundFetchResult` type. (It'll probably look something like  `completionHandler(.NewData)` if you're in Swift.)

That's basically your app's way of letting iOS know that it's done doing whatever work you wanted it to do when you sent it the remote notification. If you don't do that, iOS will get unhappy with your app and may stop forwarding it notifications in the future.

Comment: I have put a breakpoint in my implementation and it is never being called. I ended up disabling their swizzing to get it working, which was their support suggestion.

Comment: Why are you saying that you need to use `NewData`? What is `NoData` used for?